# Generally, is it possible to write kinect-like app using only C++?

Tags: c++, kinect, turing-complete, feasibility

I mean, write web-cam recognition that is close to kinect in it's accuracy.

Comment: Generally, yes. It's also generally possible in C. Or assembly. Or Java. Or python. Or ...

Comment: c++ is a general purpose language

Comment: Honestly, independent of the languages used, you probably will be unable to get the efficiency of the kinect (# and quality of sensors) because the kinect took dozens of people dozens of months.

Comment: As the hasty lynching informed you :-/ your question of "is it *possible*" is a poor phrasing. Given infinitely fast processor(s), C++ can "compute" anything that any other general purpose language could on infinitely fast processor(s). But processor(s) don't tend to be infinitely fast, plus the question of "is it practical to achieve a certain goal in real-time" is generally holistic and you have to look at issues beyond just language.  You couldn't very well make a Kinect with a camera that only takes 10x10 pixel snapshots, or a processor that can only look at one pixel a minute, could you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have an available ABI, it is possible.

In the same manner it is possible to do it in any language, including Javascript, brain fuck, and so on.

More specially, if you do it in assembly you don't even need an ABI as you can do it yourself :)

If you want to know if you can use the Kinect SDK in C++, then yes as long as you use C++/CLI with the .Net framework 4.0.

You can also find some information on alternative kinect-like sdk :
http://kinect.dashhacks.com/openni-framework

Comment: @Norbert: it stands for Application Binary Interface, and very simply, it defines how something handles and passes data(both in and out)